# WebGl disjoint timer query spikes

Tags: performance, webgl

I’m seeing some strange results when trying to time some WebGL using the disjoint timer query extension. 
I have written some simple WebGL code to reproduce the issue we are seeing here : https://jsfiddle.net/d79q3mag/2/.

```
const texImage2DQuery = gl.createQuery();
gl.beginQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT, texImage2DQuery);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32F, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, buffer);
gl.endQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT);
tex2dQuerys.push(texImage2DQuery);

const drawQuery = gl.createQuery();
gl.beginQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT, drawQuery);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); 
gl.endQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT);
drawQuerys.push(drawQuery);

tryGetNextQueryResult(tex2dQuerys, tex2dQueryResults);
tryGetNextQueryResult(drawQuerys, drawQueryResults);
```

The render function uses the timer extension to individually time the texImage2D call and the drawArrays call. If I graph the results of the draw call I see some pretty large spikes (Some as high as 12ms! but the majority of spikes in the 2ms to 4ms range) :

[image: 30FPS]

However, if I increase the framerate from 30fps to 60fps the results improve (largest spike 1.8ms most spikes between 1ms and 0.4ms) :

[image: 60FPS]

I have also noticed that if I don’t time the texImage2D function (https://jsfiddle.net/q01aejnv/2/) then the spikes in the times for the drawArrays call also disappear at 30FPS (spikes between 1.6ms and 0.2 ms).

I’m using a Quadro P4000 with chrome 81.
In the Nvidia control panel Low latency mode is set to Ultra and the power management mode is set to Prefer maximum performance. 
These results were gathered using D3D11 as the ANGLE graphics backend in chrome.

There seems to be 2 confusing things here. First is that a higher framerate seems to improve the draw times. Second is that timing the texImage2D seems to be affecting the draw times.

Comment: There are a zillion things that could be happening behind the scene but just at a glance have you tried calling `gl.flush` after `gl.endQuery`?

Comment: @gman looks like you have zoned in on the 1 in a zillion things! That fixed the issue, seems so simple now... Thanks. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing timing things you probably need to `gl.flush` after `gl.endQuery`

Explanation: WebGL functions add commands to a command buffer. Some other process reads that buffer but there is overhead in telling the other process "hey! I added some commands for you!". So, in general, WebGL commands don't always do they "Hey!" part they just insert the commands. WebGL will do an auto flush (a "Hey! Execute this!) at various points automatically but when doing timing you may need to add a `gl.flush`.

Note: Like I said above there is overhead to flushing. In a normal program it's rarely important to do a `flush`.